# Angular ShadowDom, packages are not working inside the ShadowDom component

Tags: angular, shadow-dom

I have a simple angular component that is displaying some other component from a package (angular-editor from kolkov). The package does not function correctly and fail to find elements somehow. I looked a bit deeper and discovered that the package can not find anything under `this`.

For example,

```
this.r.removeClass(elementById, 'active');
```

throws an error of `Cannot read property 'classList' of null`.

Is there something else I have to configure?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: BTW, the component has its encapsulation set to ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom. The reason for that is to prevent any CSS files loaded with the angular-editor to overlap with the global CSS in place of my application.